# Validate a string based on certain Format

Tags: c#, .net, validation, model-view-controller

I need to validate a input string based on certain formats i.e

Proj-######## (4 alphabets, 1 Dash and 8 numbers)

```
OP###### (2 characters, 6 numbers)
```

Can someone please help me on this?

I tried with the below approach it's working for 1 dash and 8 numbers. but am not geeting how to add code into regerx for allow only 4 charactes.

```
private static readonly Regex boxNumberRegex = new Regex(@"^\d-\d{8}$");

public static bool VerifyBoxNumber (string boxNumber)
{
return boxNumberRegex.IsMatch(boxNumber);
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code you have already tried to solve your task with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`\b[a-zA-Z]{4}-\d{6}\b`     - is for Proj-########
`\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}\b`      - is for OP######

If you want to learn bulding regular expressions, have a look at this article. Worth reading it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: Hi Asker, Thanks for your solution. it's working great. But i have a question here. If i want to validate input string for different formats because some times i need to validate the input with user defined format. i dont know which format it is. i need to validate on dynamic functionality.  Your suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If the input is dynamic,then is there any rules like "if a number is present in any place it must be within some range, if a character is present only certain characters alone are permitted, if hyphen'-' symbol is present the it must preced some n-digits/characters" ?